Routing TCP/IP traffic from a local subnet to 127.0.0.1
Context
I have a Windows 11 computer. Attached to it is a USB-C to Ethernet network adapter, and the adapter has a static IP assigned of 192.168.42.1 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0. The USB-C to Ethernet network adapter is connected, via the Ethernet/RJ-45 end, to a hardware device. The hardware device is assigned the IP address 192.168.42.2.
On my computer, I have a Python TCP/IP server running on localhost or 127.0.0.1 on port 8800.
server = await asyncio.start_server(connection_handler, "127.0.0.1", 8800)

Problem
I want to send a TCP/IP request from the hardware device at IP 192.168.42.2 to the TCP/IP server running on localhost/127.0.0.1. How do I do this?
What I've tried

I have tried adding a route to Windows' route table via:
route -p add 192.168.42.3 MASK 255.255.255.0 127.0.0.1

Then I configured my hardware device to send TCP/IP requests to IP 192.168.42.3 and port 8800. This doesn't seem to be working. I can't even get this to work locally by having a Python client, local to my Windows computer, send a TCP/IP request to 192.168.42.3 and have it work, even after assigning one of my unused network adapters to that IP address.

I thought that I could bind my local Python TCP/IP server to a different IP, such as one on the 192.168.42._ subnet, but I don't know how to do that.

I also tried having my test Python client (and then eventually the hardware device itself) send TCP/IP requests to the actual IP of my computer and not localhost/127.0.0.1, but that didn't work either.


As you can tell, I am a software developer with only enough networking knowledge to get by. So, thank you for any help!
Full program
Here is a simple example of a TCP/IP server:
import asyncio

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

    print(f"Received {message!r} from {addr!r}")

    print(f"Send: {message!r}")
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()

    print("Close the connection")
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    addrs = ', '.join(str(sock.getsockname()) for sock in server.sockets)
    print(f'Serving on {addrs}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())

This sever is running locally on my Windows computer.
Then, I want to be able to run the following client either locally to my Windows computer (to simulate some device on the local network) or on the hardware device that is configured to have the static IP described above:
import asyncio

async def tcp_echo_client(message):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
        'WHAT IP ADDRESS GOES HERE?', 8888)

    print(f'Send: {message!r}')
    writer.write(message.encode())
    await writer.drain()

    data = await reader.read(100)
    print(f'Received: {data.decode()!r}')

    print('Close the connection')
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()

asyncio.run(tcp_echo_client('Hello World!'))


In the call to asyncio.start_server, replace 127.0.0.1 with 192.168.42.1. Also, in the client program, in the call to asyncio.open_connection, also use 192.168.42.1.
The whole point of binding to the loopback/localhost address (127.0.0.1) is so that only the local host can reach it. Trying to set up routing so that some other device can reach your device's loopback address is…not a good approach.

for protocols like HTTP(S) that can use application layer gateways, you can deploy a reverse proxy on the host to proxy remote traffic to localhost ports, but that probably won;t work for pure TCP or binary-data application layer communications so Im guessing that a socks proxy probably cannot access 127.0.0.1 but you can give it a shot

You can bind the python server to 0.0.0.0 to accept connections on any interface. You could also bind it to that specific adapter (192.168.42.1), but the host will need to connect using that same IP instead of "localhost".
Then the client should connect to the host at the adapter IP: 192.168.42.1

127.0.0.1 is not routable - it should only be used when you explicitly don't want any communication from another device.
